# Independent volume for headphones

Tags: 11.10, sound, headphones, hda-intel

I have an Asus K52Jc and in sound configuration there is no independent sound device for the headphones, and so there's no way to have independent volume for speakers and headphones.

Is there a way to have independent devices? Or is this hardware specific?

lshw reports that I have an "Intel 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio".

aplay -l reports:

```
placa 0: Intel [HDA Intel], dispositivo 0: CONEXANT Analog [CONEXANT Analog]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
placa 0: Intel [HDA Intel], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to automatically change volume level when un-/plugging headphones?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23508/how-to-automatically-change-volume-level-when-un-plugging-headphones)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it looks like that the device driver for your headphones isn't installed - Can you check to see if it's showing as installed?

```
    card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: ALC889 Digital [ALC889 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Headset [Logitech G930 Headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

This is what my output looks like, and I can have separate audio output/input for both speakers and headphone

Comment: You have USB headphones, right? I want independent volume for normal 3.5 jack headphones.