# How to pause VLC playback when the headphones are disconnected?

Tags: vlc, headphones, video-player, playback

How is it possible to pause the playback of VLC when my headphones are plugged out?
I can mute the speakers via ALSA, but I want to use the plug trigger to stop the playback, as it is usual in smartphones.

Comment: Notice: the second answer is much more efficient at the time of writing: http://askubuntu.com/a/642898/20275

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so based on what I have learned from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640741/what-code-is-executed-when-headphones-are-disconnected), I am trying a new approach, using ACPI.

1. Create a script, for pausing and unpausing VLC:

   ```
   sudo touch /etc/acpi/headphone_jack.sh
   sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/headphone_jack.sh
   ```

   and place the following on this file:

   ```
   _pid=`pgrep vlc`
   _pid="${_pid% *}"
   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=`grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$_pid/environ | sed -e 's/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//'`
   _username=`grep -z USER= /proc/$_pid/environ |sed 's/.*=//'`

   if [ "$3" = unplug ]; then
       su $_username -c "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Pause"
   else
       su $_username -c "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Play"
   fi
   ```
2. Now let's create an event trigger (replace `vim` with your favourite text editor):

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/acpi/events/headphones
   ```

   and add the following:

   ```
   event=jack/headphone
   action=/etc/acpi/headphone_jack.sh %e
   ```
3. Finally, restart the ACPI daemon:

   ```
   sudo service acpid restart
   ```

I think the should be exactly what you require, with no polling involved.
The only drawback I can find with this implementation is in case you have multiple users running VLC at the same time. I suppose in that case, what can happen is that this approach will randomly pause and resume one of them (or it might simply not work).

Big Kudos to @int_ua and @Sneetsher for providing me with important knowledge regarding ACPI event handling. Also thumbs up to @user3073656 for helping simplify the procedure.

Comment: to run any command that needs DBUS, you have to export the environment variable of the running dbus session. See Germar's comment on Sneetsher's answer.

Comment: Well spotted. Here is the cleanest way I could think of to do that. No need for autostart scripts and whatnot.

Comment: @Stunts, that's the best approach I have seen to get target ENV.  It is possible to get user same way `grep -z USER /proc/$_pid/environ` so it will work for all users in the machine (with single running session/vlc). I was looking for such option.

Comment: @Sneetsher: Sweet! Looks much better now. It crossed my mind last night, but I was too tired last night to think about it clearly. Thanks for the push in that direction.

Comment: You could still improve the answer by using %e, and using only a single script file.  See [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11803463/).

Answer (score 9):

Ok, so you will need to do a few things for this:

1. Detect when the headphones are unplugged;
2. After the event in (1), send a "pause" command to VLC;
3. Detect when the headphones are pluggd back in;
4. After the event in (3), send a "play" command to VLC;

For (1) and (3):
You can use what is shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133809/mute-sound-on-headphone-unplug).
This answer contains a small procedure to find the difference between a plugged and unplugged jack, and a script that you can modify to conform to your case.

For (2) and (4):
You should use VLC's Dbus interface.
The relevant code should be this:

`dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest=org.mpris.vlc /Player org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer.Pause`

`dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest=org.mpris.vlc /Player org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer.Play`

For pause and play respectively.

Now, about the script. In your case, it should look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This scripts detecs unplugging headphones.

oldstatus="unrelated string"
while [ 1 ]; do
    # The following line has to be changed depending on the difference (use diff) in '/proc/asound/card0/code#0'
    status=$(grep -A 4 'Node 0x16' '/proc/asound/card0/codec#0' |  grep 'Amp-Out vals:  \[0x80 0x80\]')
    if [ "$status" != "$oldstatus" ]; then
        if [ -n "$status" ]; then
            echo "Plugged in"
             dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest=org.mpris.vlc /Player org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer.Play
            oldstatus="$status"
        else
            echo "Unplugged"
            dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest=org.mpris.vlc /Player org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer.Pause
            oldstatus="$status"
        fi
    fi
    # Now sleep for 250 milli-seconds as per @Serg's request (who learnt if from @Fabby)
    # sleep is timer-based so doesn't use *any* processor cycles while sleeping.
    sleep 0.25
done
```

Add this modified script to your startup applications, and you're set. I think it should do what you wanted to.

PS - Note that there are more efficient ways to do this, such as using `inotify` to detect event changes (and maybe even other approaches), but this one should get you started (and the others are above my skill level and experience). I suppose you can start with this "hackish" approach, and build up from here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's really helpful. I'll reward the points in case no better answer is posted. The only thing I don't like is the constant polling, I've created a separate question for that: http://askubuntu.com/questions/640741/what-code-is-executed-when-headphones-are-disconnected

Comment: I'll follow that question! I could use that knowledge.

Comment: You could add a `sleep 0.25` at the end, which is a quarter of a second delay. That eases up on CPU and still works fast enough. I use this sometimes in my own scripts,too

Comment: ACPI handles headphones unplug, will you add this to your answer? http://askubuntu.com/a/642404/20275

Comment: Awesome! I will work something with it tonight.

Comment: Using ACPI events made the final result so different from the original solution that I have chosen to give a new answer instead.