# Several ACPI event keys have the same ID

Tags: 14.04, kernel, keyboard, acpi, function-keys

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Kernel: 3.19.0-37-generic

## INTRO

When I start `acpi_listen` on my system I can test several LaptopSpecialKeys. The brightness buttons work perfectly fine for example:

```
video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000
video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000
```

The desired function is working.

## PROBLEM

If I test some other keys, they either have no acpi event triggered at all (acpi_listen does nothing) or several keys are mapped to the same code like the three volume keys:

```
button/volumeup VOLUP 00000080 00000000 K
button/volumedown VOLDN 00000080 00000000 K
button/mute MUTE 00000080 00000000 K
```

The result of the volume keys being mapped to the same code is that the volume up, down and mute actions are all behaving very weird. E.g. if I press volume up function key the volume up event is triggered infinitely repeating.

#### And the weirdest thing of all:

How does the acpi event distinguish between those three keys, recognizing that each has its own funcionality (VOLUP, VOLDN, MUTE), altough all three keys have the same code 0x80?

## QUESTION

Do you have any idea on how to handle such problems with acpi events? Is it a problem of the kernel, not recognizing specific notebook drivers? Or are there solutions on the user level that might repair this broken functionality of LaptopSpecialKeys?

Answer (score 1):

Actually they are very distinguishable, your script will receive the whole line as argument. Example:

```
button/volumeup VOLUP 00000080 00000000 K
```

You got 5 arguments and you are free how to process them.

Maybe the easiest way:

```
event=button/*
action=/etc/acpi/yourscript.sh %e
```

Then in your script used the 3rd argument `$3` that will either `VOLUP`, `VOLDN` or `MUTE`, plus some other buttons (power,...) .

See:

- [What code is executed when headphones are disconnected?](https://askubuntu.com/q/640741/26246)
- [How to pause VLC playback when the headphones are disconnected?](https://askubuntu.com/q/521371/26246)