# Finding correct input of FN+F11 to use as shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xev

I'm currently setting up gestures using [Touchegg](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg). Most of them are fairly easy, but I want to bind <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> which is causing me some trouble.

As far as I understand it FN is not an actual key, but more of a physical switch for my laptop, so it doesn't have an actual "Key" I can use as a modifier in my settings.

Using `xev` I managed to print out the output of my keypresses, but I'm unsure how to use it in my configuration:

#### Pressing and releasing <kbd>F11</kbd>

```
FocusOut event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor
```

#### Pressing and releasing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x1c9, subw 0x0, time 17878429, (-72,69), root:(799,536),
    state 0x0, keycode 95 (keysym 0xffc8, F11), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x1c9, subw 0x0, time 17878519, (-72,69), root:(799,536),
    state 0x0, keycode 95 (keysym 0xffc8, F11), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Any idea what key combination I should use?

Comment: Check ACPI, it may show something, see this question https://askubuntu.com/q/706188/26246

Comment: That seems to be working for brightness and volume, but not for my specific case

Comment: AFAIK, those are the only ways to detect input keys X/libinput and ACPI. Fn (major implementation if not all) is only at BIOS or UEFI, not the OS.

Comment: I think the answer is in your question: you cannot reassign Fn+other keys.

Comment: What key combination should you use for what? Notice this odd behavior can usually be reverted in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you could create a file named `.Xmodmap` in your home directory. (Note the "dot" in the beginning).

So I tested with xev the combination of Fn+F11 and got this info:

```
KeyPress event, serial 42, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
root 0x1b6, subw 0x0, time 4047518, (14,98), root:(5045,739),
state 0x0, keycode 128 (keysym 0x1008ff4a, XF86LaunchA), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

You can see that the keycode of this combination is 128 on **my device** (yours may be a different one)

Next I want to change that combination to -say XF86AudioMute (or whatever you want) and test it:
`xmodmap -e "keycode 128 = XF86AudioMute NoSymbol XF86AudioMute"`

If I press the combination `Fn+F11` my audio toggles. To persist this behaviour add it to the `.Xmodmap`file in you home directory. Create it if is doesn't exist:

```
keycode 128 = XF86AudioMute NoSymbol XF86AudioMute
```

Instead of using XF86AudioMute you could also use XF86Launch1 or anything else that you can find in this list:

`xmodmap -pke`

Last not least use your chosen value to connect this event with an executable.

[More infos on Xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap#Finding_the_keysym_column_modifier_keys)

An alternative would be [Xbindkeys](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xbindkeys.1.html) which might also work to tackle your problem. A more elaborate documentation can be found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys)

Comment: Could you explain how I would figure out that equation? I'm really unclear of what this is supposed to do

Comment: See my revised answer. Do you get a XEV output when you press the FN button all by itself?

Comment: So, once I map the keycode, what do I do with `XF86Launch1`? Does that become an alias for the key combination I can use inside Touchegg? I will try this as soon as I get home and let you know! Thank you :)

Comment: Yes. In my case I could use the XF86LaunchA directly, but since your combination of Fn+F11 results to F11 the line should read: `keycode 95 = XF86Launch1 NoSymbol XF86Launch1`

Comment: If it worked and solves your problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!