# Script doesn't work from udev

Tags: scripts, kubuntu, udev

I have some trouble with running script from udev rule. It works normal if I will run it from terminal, but one command doesn't work when udev rule run this script.

Udev rule: `/etc/udev/rules.d/84-test-rule.rules`

```
ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/sblock.sh >> /home/username/udev_test_log.txt'"
```

Script: `/usr/bin/sblock.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello, its script from udev udev_test_log.txt # this line wors normal
xdg-screensaver lock # but screen not block
```

I expect, that my system will blocks every time I remove usb-flash (I have planned to add some properties of my usb-drive later). But after removing flash I have only line in file `udev_test_log.txt`.

System -- kubuntu 16.04

Comment: Have you made it executable?

Comment: Yes. And it runs -- first command of script write ine in file /home/username/udev_test_log.txt. But next command works only if launch script from terminal

Comment: Please fix the typos in your question. Is it `#!/bun/bash` or `#!/bin/bash`? If you have a shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`) and have made the script executable, why are you running with `bash -c`? More importantly, what fails? Is the `echo Hello` line printed? What were you expecting to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: @Manch, I expect you need to define the environment variable for display and dbus before calling xdg-screensaver. see this example https://askubuntu.com/a/642898/26246

Comment: Maybe it can get an answer with explanation though @DavidFoerster? It doesn't look exactly the same though the principle may be