# How to play music when earphones are plugged in and pause it as soon as they are removed?

Tags: music, clementine

If it can be done using mimicking the function keys play and pause, or I want it in clementine only so using the clementine command line.

Answer (score 0):

Clementine supports standard Global Hotkeys, such as Multimedia Keys, as well as custom setups.  Your best bet would be to modify [this post on how to mute audio when your headset becomes disconnected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133809/mute-sound-on-headphone-unplug) to send the Multimedia Pause key.

Basically, a file (/proc/asound/card0/codec#0) will change depending upon whether or not headphones are connected.  You would monitor this file (inotify) and depending on the file's content, send the Multimedia Pause.