# What code is executed when headphones are disconnected?

Tags: headphones, soundcard, monitoring

I want to execute a script on headphones disconnect but I resent the idea of [constant polling](https://askubuntu.com/a/133829/20275) of the status when there is already some code executed when it's changed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In most systems if not all, ACPI can handle this event. To test that:

1. Run `acpi_listen`
2. Unplug & replug headphones, example output: (mic/ears share in same jack on my laptop)

   ```
   jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug
   jack/microphone MICROPHONE unplug
   jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug
   jack/microphone MICROPHONE plug
   ```
3. Put `your-script.sh` in `/etc/acpi/`
4. Add an event trigger file for your script in `/etc/acpi/events/`

   ```
   event=jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug
   action=/etc/acpi/your-script.sh
   ```

   Check the other files there to learn from.
5. You may need to restart `acpid` service to reload changed rules in `/etc/acpi/events/`

   ```
   sudo service acpid restart
   ```

**Reference:** [`man acpid`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/acpid.8.html)

Comment: Now I just have to find out how to make dbus work from ACPI scrips, but that's a different question.

Comment: @int_ua you need to write `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environ variable into a file in your homedir with a script started with `~/.config/autostart/dbus.desktop`. Then you can run `su YOURUSER -c "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(cat ~/.dbus_address) amixer ......."` from `/etc/acpi/your-script.sh`

Comment: Hey, I wrote a script to show a notification. Followed exactly what you said. My script executes notify-send "Headphones connected" on plug event. BUt it doesn't seem to work. http://askubuntu.com/questions/877804/notify-send-on-headphones-plugged

Answer (score 1):

The current version of your script now contains a `sleep 0.25` command.

`sleep` is timer-based so doesn't use *any* processing cycles while sleeping…

It does use a very tiny bit of CPU to set up the timer, but `sleep 1` (sleep 1 second), `sleep 60` (sleep for a minute) and `sleep 86400` (sleep for a day)  all use the same number CPU cycles.

[Using ACPI](https://askubuntu.com/a/642404/344926) however is the *perfect* solution as ACPI is event-driven instead of polling-driven.