# How to try hibernation and shutdown afterward in case it failed on power button press?

Tags: shutdown, hibernate, systemd-logind

I've found how to hibernate on power button press with logind:

```
HandlePowerKey=hibernate
```

in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

But can I make it somehow execute something like

```
# pm-hibernate || shutdown -h
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- No, you can't make that setup using `HandlePowerKey` entry for `systemd`. It is not a script hook, just a predefined options.

  > **`HandlePowerKey=, HandleSuspendKey=, HandleHibernateKey=, HandleLidSwitch=, HandleLidSwitchDocked=`**
  >
  > Controls whether logind shall handle the system power and sleep keys and the lid switch to trigger actions such as system power-off or suspend. **Can be one of "ignore", "poweroff", "reboot", "halt", "kexec", "suspend", "hibernate", "hybrid-sleep", and "lock". If "ignore", logind will never handle these keys.** If "lock", all running sessions will be screen-locked; otherwise, the specified action will be taken in the respective event. Only input devices with the "power-switch" udev tag will be watched for key/lid switch events. HandlePowerKey= defaults to "poweroff". HandleSuspendKey= and HandleLidSwitch= default to "suspend". HandleLidSwitchDocked= defaults to "ignore". HandleHibernateKey= defaults to "hibernate". If the system is inserted in a docking station, or if more than one display is connected, the action specified by HandleLidSwitchDocked= occurs; otherwise the HandleLidSwitch= action occurs.

  **Reference:** [`man logind.conf`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html#HandlePowerKey=)
- One way that may work, set it to `ignore` then setup a poweroff key hook through `/etc/acpi/events/` as explained in [What code is executed when headphones are disconnected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640741/what-code-is-executed-when-headphones-are-disconnected/642404#642404) ( It's your question, right :) )