# systemd: How to modify the HandlePowerKey action with a custom command?

Tags: 15.04, power-management, shutdown, acpi, systemd

My headless server has a power button.

When the user presses it, I want the server to respond with a brief beep, then shutdown the server.

The system should only beep when manually pressing the power button, not when the system shuts down on its own (e.g. when idle).

systemd [handles the ACPI event from the power button](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html), but how can I add a beep to `HandlePowerKey` there?

Comment: Answering this will also answer that question: http://askubuntu.com/q/644434/20275

Answer (score 0):

this question was solved here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1974

you just need to add that command like

> echo -e "\a"

to execution of power button event.

it uses "beep" package, so you should install it before

> sudo apt-get install beep

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to make the beep. What I don't know is how to make systemd emit a beep when the power button is pressed. The solution you link to is not for systemd.