# How do I automatically switch PulseAudio input to headset upon connection?

Tags: 18.04, pulseaudio, headset, peripherals

Using Xubuntu 18.04, I have a headset that I connect, with its own microphone input. Every time I connect it, I then have to launch `pavucontrol`, click to the "Input Devices" tab, then select the "Headset Microphone" (instead of "Internal Microphone") in the "Port" drop down menu.

Whenever I disconnect the headset, the "Port" gets switched back to "Internal Microphone", so I have to repeat the process the next time I connect the headset.

Is there a way to do this automatically, or with minimal effort on my part?

I searched online and saw the advice to ensure the PulseAudio `module-switch-on-connect` is loaded, but I checked `pactl list short modules` and it appears to be already loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I almost fix it on my laptop running Debian 10 this way:

1. Unplug your headset.
2. Edit `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` — set `log-level = debug`
3. Restart pulseaudio: `pulseaudio -k`
4. Run `journalctl --follow` in a separate terminal/tmux window
5. Plug in your headset and watch what happens. `module-alsa-card.c: Jack 'Headphone Mic Jack' is now plugged in` says which jack is detected
6. Edit `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input-headset-mic.conf`, find the `[Jack Headphone Mic]` section and change `state.plugged` from `unknown` to `yes`

I said "almost", because

1. Mic gain did not restore
2. It does not distinguish external loudspeakers (TRS jack) and headset (TRRS jack) and switch input source anyway, so I get static noise instead of internal mic audio.

[The blog post](https://aweirdimagination.net/2018/12/16/pulseaudio-headphone-jack-troubles/) guided me this direction.

Comment: Worked, thanks!  I just wish there was a way to restore the microphone gain as well...

Answer (score 1):

The solution sent above works for some PCs, but not for all. I tested solutions for a long time that I could find in the documentation or on forums and this was the only one that worked.

So here is a script that I created that you can add when starting a session (unfortunately not for the entire computer because PulseAudio is a service that runs independently for each user).

```
#!/bin/bash
index=$(pacmd list-sources | egrep 'index|ports|analog-input-headset-mic' | egrep '\*\sindex:\s+[0-9]'  | cut -d':' -f2);

acpi_listen | while IFS= read -r line;
do
    if [ "$line" = "jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug" ]
    then
       pacmd set-source-port $index analog-input-headset-mic;
    elif [ "$line" = "jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug" ]
    then
       pacmd set-source-port $index analog-input-internal-mic;
    fi
done
```

This topic is part of my sources and here is another link that helped me in my research and to develop my script:

- [What code is executed when headphones are disconnected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640741/what-code-is-executed-when-headphones-are-disconnected/642404)

Comment: This worked for me in Kubuntu 21.04 and Realtek ALC3204