# How to configure HDMI as default audio when unplugging the headphones?

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, hdmi, headphones

When I unplug the headphones, the sound device is set automatically to "Digital Output (S/PDIF)" instead of the "HDMI / Displayport" that I was using before plugging the headphones.

How can I configure the system so that it uses the headphones when they are connected, and the HDMI output when they are not?  I do not want the system to use "Digital Output (S/PDIF)" at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to 'user.dz' - you can trigger a script when headphones is disconnected.

**when Headphone disconnects - use ACPI to trigger a script**

([What code is executed when headphones are disconnected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640741/what-code-is-executed-when-headphones-are-disconnected)).

> In most systems if not all, ACPI can handle this event. To test that:
>
> Run acpi_listen
>
> Unplug & replug headphones, example output: (mic/ears share in same >jack on my laptop)
>
> jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug
> jack/microphone MICROPHONE unplug
> jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug
> jack/microphone MICROPHONE plug
>
> Put your-script.sh in /etc/acpi/
>
> Add an event trigger file for your script in /etc/acpi/events/
>
> event=jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug
> action=/etc/acpi/your-script.sh
>
> Check the other files there to learn from.
>
> You may need to restart acpid service to reload changed rules in >/etc/acpi
> /events/
>
> sudo service acpid restart

**Default Headphone setting within terminal for the script**

Could be done with recommendation to 'Takkat's answer from

([How can I change the default audio device from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line))

> You can control PulseAudio thoroughly through the command line using pacmd and >pactl commands. For options see man pages or the wiki at PulseAudio:
>
> pacmd list-sinks (or pactl list short sinks) for name or index number of possible >sinks
>
> pacmd set-default-sink "SINKNAME" to set the default output sink
>
> pacmd set-default-source "SOURCENAME" to set the default input
>
> pacmd set-sink-volume index volume
>
> pacmd set-source-volume index volume for volume control (65536 = 100 %, 0 = mute; or a bit more intuitive 0x10000 = 100 %, 0x7500 = 75 %, 0x0 = 0 %)
>
> and many many more CLI options.

This is my first answer - I hope it helps and pardon/let me know if theres anything I should've done differently.

Comment: Thanks!  The only think missing from your reply was adding this line before the pacmd in the script:  `export PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH="/run/user/<your user id>/pulse/"`   This is needed because ACPI scripts run as root and pulse audio runs and the logged user.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it breaks Ubuntu sound configuration.  Now when I go to the Sound Settings window it is empty, there are no output devices...

Comment: To avoid breaking Ubuntu sound settings you should use `action=/bin/su -c "/etc/acpi/your_script.sh" - your_username`

Comment: Thanks alot for the details - think I'll do the same myself now! - cheers ~