# How can I keep muted when unplugging headphones?

Tags: gnome, sound, headphones

I have this workflow:

1. Listen through headphones
2. Press mute button on my keyboard
3. Unplug my headphones to move away

I noticed that at least on GNOME, audio keeps playing.

How can I configure this mute button to keep muted after unplugging headphones?

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133809/mute-sound-on-headphone-unplug) ?

Comment: Thanks! Surprised to see it needs scripting. Will request this feature for GNOME upstream. :-)

Comment: I think we are just used to this feature because of smartphones :)

Comment: @RobertRiedl yeah but it is a brilliant feature! :-D Sometimes I forget about this, unplug my headphones and surprise my coworkers with my music. Not very elegant. ;-)

Comment: ...as long as it is not "organ"-music, *wink-wink*,*nudge-nudge* ;-)

Comment: Usually classical radio music ;-)

Comment: ah, then you should be fine ! What I did, with a laptop that has (due to the docking station) both a LINE out and a headphone jack, I just plugged an open cable into the lineout - Ubuntu seems to default to the line-out output, if I unplug my headphones or disconnect my bluetooth headset.

Comment: My laptop doesn't support lineout. :-( Anyway, here is the bug report. [Bug 793305](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=793305)