# Can I auto-start music player after connecting headphones?

Tags: autostart, music-player

Is there a way to start my default music player after connecting the headphones or earphones ?

If there is nothing in the form of a GUI, I don't mind writing a script for it, but I need some starting guidance, which is where do I write the script?

I am connecting the headphones through the 3.5mm jack.

Comment: This is going to be dependent on what hardware you have. First thing to sort out is 'jack detection' (not what it sounds like) which is covered in [this related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23508/how-to-automatically-change-volume-level-when-un-plugging-headphones).